# Short and frequent freeze on Raspberry Pi 4 with Kali Linux 64bit

Tags: pi-4, kali, 64-bit

I installed [Kali Linux RaspberryPi 2 (v1.2), 3 and 4 64-Bit](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#1493408272250-e17e9049-9ce8)
on my Raspberry Pi 4 with 4Gb RAM.

All is running very well but I frequently experience a freeze, about 10 seconds of total interruption of all applications.

I tried to change SD card and to keep CPU cold but without success.

Before and during the freeze the system log itself is freezed. A little before I find some messages regarding to wifi but I think that they are not pertinent because they always periodically appear.

```
kernel: [41757.613100] brcmfmac: _brcmf_set_multicast_list: Setting allmulti failed, -110
kernel: [41760.173154] brcmfmac: _brcmf_set_multicast_list: Setting BRCMF_C_SET_PROMISC failed, -110
wpa_supplicant[568]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-110
kernel: [41762.733156] brcmfmac: brcmf_run_escan: error (-110
```

I wonder if this is a problem of the 64bit kernel port or what?

***Update:***

Unfortunately I didn't find the reason for the freeze that occur mainly when I interact with GUIs. I followed the Dmitry Grigoryev's suggestion, wrote the script, tried to eliminate processes but the freeze remained.

At the end I installed official 32bit Raspbian and enriched it with all Kali Linux tools: no more freeze.

By the way, what the advantages of running a 64bit OS on a 4Gb RAM machine? But this is another question...

Comment: Have you looked at the system logs after this happens?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will update my question if I succeed.

Answer (score 2):

Write a script writing / printing current time every second, and run it as `root` with `nice -20`. If the log is not interrupted during the freeze, it's likely user-space, at which point killing persistent processes and waiting for the freeze to happen may find the culprit. If all userspace processes are frozen regardless of priority, then it's likely a kernel/driver issue. You could try to weed out a faulty kernel module by removing it and observing no more freezes, but if it's in the kernel itself there's not much you can do short of debugging.

Comment: Good suggestion, I wrote the script and it seems that it is not interrupted during the freeze so now I have to investigate the processes in user-space. I will update my question if I discover something.